# How to show stored procedure values to datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE abc
AS
    SELECT CustomerID 
    FROM Customers 
    WHERE CustomerID < 10

    SELECT GuarantorID 
    FROM Guarantors 
    WHERE GuarantorID < 10
```

I have two columns in my datagridview. I want to show `CustomerID` in one column and `GuarantorID` in the second column

My C# code does not show any value on datagridview

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.abc", conn))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("abc",conn);

        sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;                      
    }        
}
```

Comment: Your procedure produces 2 resultsets. Since you are trying to fill 1 datatable, you should be aware of that tables are organized not only in columns but also in rows, so what pairs of `CustomerID` and `GuarantorID` do you expect to appear together in the same row? Also: don't forget do "databind" the gridview.

Comment: both are independet from each other

Comment: Then you need 2 datatables and 2 gridviews (and 2 separate procedures/queries).

Comment: ok. is it possible to show my required data in ListBox control ??

Comment: Again: If you want to display "unrelated" data side-by-side, you (or your customer) must define some kind of "relation", so one SELECT statement can return values from both tables side-by-side. This applies to any kind of control (gridview, listbox or whatever) that is designed to display "relational" data like a table.